# How do I embed a FLV file (stored in the HD) into my web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, flv

I am developing a **MVC3** application with **C#** and **Razor**. I want to create a web page where an FLV file, stored in the hard disk, is played.

I found a lot of material on how to do it in WordPress but there is no link that explains how to do it in **normal HTML**.

May anybody help me or provide me resources in order to perform this task?

Thanks in advance

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a player to play .flv file on HTML page. You cannot play .flv files out of the box in HTML page without any flash application that can playback those files.

this is player i would advice you to use [JW player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

this is short example how to embed a file

**div with player id** is where your player will be rendered.

**jwplayer.js** is js file that allows you to play files and make all calls needed to .swf player below

**'flashplayer':    '/jwplayer/player.swf',** is where player located without which you will be not able to playback the file. **Attention on URL**

**'file':       '/videos/video.mp4'** is where your local .flv file is related to IIS server. **Attention on URL**

```
<div id='player'>This div will be replaced by the JW Player.</div>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        'flashplayer':  '/jwplayer/player.swf',
        'width':    '400',
        'height':   '300',
        'file':     '/videos/video.mp4'
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I would like to use each time a different file how can I pass the path to the javascript?

Comment: I can't say for sure but obviously JW Player documentation made some input on this issue. Sorry can't help you there. You can re-ask question ie. how to embed dynamic .flv files on page.